# <Input type="number"> how add specific number validation along with min and max number?

Tags: angularjs, validation, input

what I'm trying to do here is next

I need a simple input that allows for numbers from 5 to 10, and 0

```
`<input type="number" 
       required ng-model="item.quantity"
       ng-min="5"
       ng-max="10"/>`
```

this is my code but it now valid when user insert 0

Comment: so what's the point in that? use a select or something

Comment: and you can also use a getterSetter - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions (Check the example of **Connecting to the scope**)

Comment: what about `ng-pattern` with some regex range for numbers between 5 and 10?

Answer (score 1):

For this regex:

```
ng-pattern="/^(0|[5-9]|10)$/"
```

The following are valid:

0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Answer (score 0):

Use like,

html:

```
<input type="number" required ng-model="item.quantity"/>
```

controller:

```
$scope.$watch("item.quantity", function() {
 var quantity = parseInt(item.quantity);
 if(quantity => 5 || quantity == 0) {
    //To do
  } else {
    $scope.item.quantity = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: then prefer like,

`<input type="number" ng-init = "quantity = (item.quantity >= 5 || item.quantity ==0) ? item.quantity : null"required ng-model="quantity"/>`

Comment: The OP is absolutely right - This answer is not good, and the second suggestion does not make it any better

Comment: I believe I will use ng-change and validate numbers in controller

Comment: @OlegLozynskyi Check the second comment I posted under your question, I think getterSetter would do the trick - It will give you a chance to validate the input before assigning it to the model

Comment: Then use like,

<input type="number" required ng-model="item.quantity" ng-change = "changeQuantity(item.quantity)"/>

Controller:

$scope.changeQuantity = function(quantity) {
if(condition) {
//Todo logic here
}
}